# How to get First and Second Level List using JSON only

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting data into ListView using JSON, but for the first Level List, i am using static code, in short first level list not getting using JSON, see below code using to show first level List.

*Category Screen* **(showing data in a Static way)**

[image]

*Product Screen* **(getting data using JSON)**

[image]

**CategoryActivity.java:**

```
public class CategoriesActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

ListView lview3;
ListViewCustomAdapter adapter;

private ArrayList<Object> itemList;
private ItemBean bean;

ImageButton checkOut;
ImageButton back;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menus);    

    prepareArrayLits();
    lview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(this, itemList);
    lview3.setAdapter(adapter);
    lview3.setOnItemClickListener(this);  

}
private static final int Sony = 0;
private static final int Panasonic = 1;

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {

         // Set up different intents based on the item clicked: 
         switch (position)
         {
             case Sony:
                 Intent intent1 = new Intent(CategoriesActivity.this, ProductsActivity.class);
                 intent1.putExtra("category", "Sony");
                    startActivity(intent1); 
                 break;
             case Panasonic:
                 Intent intent2 = new Intent(CategoriesActivity.this, ProductsActivity.class);
                 intent2.putExtra("category", "Panasonic");
                    startActivity(intent2); 
                 break;

             default:
                 break;
         }

     }

public void prepareArrayLits()
{
    itemList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    AddObjectToList( "Sony" );
    AddObjectToList( "Panasonic" );

}

// Add one item into the Array List
public void AddObjectToList(String title)
{
    bean = new ItemBean();
    bean.setTitle(title);
    itemList.add(bean);
}

}
```

**ItemBean.java:**

```
public class ItemBean 
{
    String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

**ListViewCustomAdapter.java:**

```
public class ListViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<Object> itemList;

    public Activity context;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListViewCustomAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<Object> itemList) {
        super();

        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = itemList;     
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView txtViewTitle;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_categories, null);
            holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        ItemBean bean = (ItemBean) itemList.get(position);
        holder.txtViewTitle.setText(bean.getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

and to get data into Second Level List (i.e: Products List), using below code,

**ProductsActivity.java:-**

```
public class ProductsActivity extends Activity {


    static String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/android/test.json";

    static String KEY_CATEGORY = "item";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "ProductName";

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menus);

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, itemsList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            new MyAsyncTask().execute();
        } else {

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProductsActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setMessage("The Internet connection appears to be offline.");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (info != null);
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                ProductsActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading, Please wait.....");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
                String... params) {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // Perform a GET request for a JSON list
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(URL);
            // Get the response that sends back
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = client.execute(request);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Convert this response into a readable string
            String jsonString = null;
            try {
                jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response.getEntity()
                        .getContent());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Create a JSON object that we can use from the String
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(KEY_CATEGORY);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    map.put("KEY", String.valueOf(i));
                    map.put(KEY_TITLE, jsonObject.getString(KEY_TITLE));

                    itemsList.add(map);

                }
                return itemsList;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            adapter = new LazyAdapter(ProductsActivity.this, itemsList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

**LazyAdapter.java:**

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_products, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); 

        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        item = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(item.get(ProductsActivity.KEY_TITLE));

        return vi;
    }
}
```

**StreamUtils.java:-**

```
public class StreamUtils {

    public static String convertToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();

            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            try {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 1024);
                int n;
                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            return writer.toString();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:**

How to get First Level List by using JSON, not by writing static code like i have written in my existing program?

**test.json:**

```
{
    "Sony": [{
        "ProductID": "1",
        "ProductName": "Sony - LED TV"
    }, {
        "ProductID": "2",
        "ProductName": "Sony - Laptop"
    }],

    "Panasonic": [{
        "ProductID": "1",
        "ProductName": "Panasonic - LED TV"
    }, {
        "ProductID": "2",
        "ProductName": "Panasonic - Laptop"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Because this question makes no sense, you should try to use some of the lingo as found in Json to describe levels, as it stands currently your question is not clear on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Check tutorials : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can write an asynctask for generating first level list using json parsing. Now, in your activity, you can have a datastructure like map, arraylist etc for holding the first level list. In onCreate of the application, you can call your asynctask to do json parsing can fill you local data structure which you can then use to show first level list.

Or

you can redesign your app in a simpler way. Keep a single listview with an adapter. And on clicking any item in the list, you can change the dataset of your listview.

Something like this:

public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

if(isLevel1Column1) {
   mAdapter_1.setListData(mSubMenu1);
   isLevel1Column1 = false;
   mAdapter_1.notifyDataSetChanged();

I have achieved something like this before. in my case also, i used lazyloading code :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are getting the json from the web service. The better approach will be to actually modify your json response in a way which will give the category name and array both. At present the way your json is structured is probably not correct. Now, you have only two products i.e. sony and panasonic but that may increase. So, better modify your json in a way which gives category name and its listing probably in a way as mentioned below :

```
[
    {
         "categoryName" : "Sony",
         "categoryList" : [{"ProductID": "1",
                            "ProductName": "Sony - LED TV"},
                           {"ProductID": "2",
                            "ProductName": "Sony - Laptop"}]
   },

   {
         "categoryName" : "Panasonic",
         "categoryList" : [{"ProductID": "1",
                            "ProductName": "Panasonic - LED TV"},
                           {"ProductID": "2",
                            "ProductName": "Panasonic - Laptop"}]
   }    
]
```

This way you can get the names dynamically as well the listing. Hope this helps you out.

If you just want to populate the listview with static strings then you can create a string array and use the code as mentioned below :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: but my problem is not with JSON, i just want to know how to get data into ListView for First Level, because i am showing categories in a static way... getting my point?

Comment: can you also show me the code to get data into ListView in Android ? @mobiledev

Comment: I am not sure if I am getting you correctly but I have edited the answer in case you just want to populate static strings in listview.

Comment: ok now leave all, can i have a code to get data into Listview using above JSON you have written?

Comment: What did you tried for get data into Listview using above JSON ?

Comment: @mobiledev My requirement is simple first need to show List of Categories (like: Sony, Panasonic) and then show List of Products (for a Particular Category) using JSON only

Comment: You have already written code to get data into listview as mentioned above by you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    As per my understanding you require ExpandableListView which contains Parent at its first view .. When you click on any parent you get list of child under it.

   Dynamically populate parent and child to ExpandableListView using key name for parent and its object as child from JSON... ( Just change api from which you need to access data ).

    Your main class where you require to show all stuffs 
    ------------------------------------------------------

    public class ViewProfileService extends Activity{

        /** Define Async Task variables over here ..vvvv*/
        HttpClient httpclient;
        HttpGet httpget;
        HttpResponse httpresponse;
        HttpResponse hhttpresponse;
        JSONObject myJsonObject = null;
        JSONArray myJsonArray = null;
        String myJsonString = "";

        JSONObject nmyJsonObject = null;
        JSONArray nmyJsonArray = null;
        String nmyJsonString = "";
        String service;
        String name;
        ServiceList sl;
        String[] head;

        //private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    //  private ArrayList<ServiceList> m_ArrayList = null;
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////ArrayList<String[]> header = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        /** Expandable list credentials */
        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        ExpandableListView expListView;
        List<String> listDataHeader;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
         String bo_uid;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.view_profile_service);

            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("all_id", 0);
            bo_uid = sp.getString("bo_uid", "");

            new BussinessOwnerHttpAsyncTask().execute();

            //setGroupIndicatorToRight();

             /*// Create a Drawable object with states
            Drawable icon =
        this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.expander_group);

            // Set the newly created Drawable object as group indicator.
            // Now you should be seeing your icons as group indicators.
           getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(icon);*/
        }

        class BussinessOwnerHttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();

                /*pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent());
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();*/
            }


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                StaticVars sv = new StaticVars();
                // Starting Async Task work over here ...
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
                String myUrl = "your url " ;//set you url over here

                myUrl = myUrl.replaceAll("\n", "");
                myUrl = myUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                Log.d("checkurl", myUrl);
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(myUrl.trim());

                try {
                    httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                    System.out.println("httpresponse" + httpresponse);
                    Log.i("response", "Response" + httpresponse);
                    InputStream is = httpresponse.getEntity().getContent();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String recievingDataFromServer = null;
                    while ((recievingDataFromServer = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.i("CHECK WHILE", "CHECK WHILE");
                        sb.append(recievingDataFromServer);
                    }

                    myJsonString = sb.toString();

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            //  pDialog.dismiss();

                if (myJsonString.length() > 0) {
                    try {
                        myJsonObject = new JSONObject(myJsonString);
                        JSONObject object = myJsonObject.getJSONObject("services");

                        Iterator<String> iterate = object.keys();
                        //m_ArrayList = new ArrayList<ServiceList>();

                        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
                        List<String> toptodown = null;

                        while(iterate.hasNext()){
                             service = iterate.next();
                            Log.d("goging", service);
                            listDataHeader.add(service);
                            myJsonArray = object.getJSONArray(service);
                            toptodown = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < myJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                  JSONObject okay = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                  name = okay.getString("name");
                                  Log.d("goging","Name is: " + name);
                                  toptodown.add(name);
                                  }

                            listDataChild.put(service, toptodown);

                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
                start();

            }

        }



        public void start() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        }

    }

    your view_profile_service.xml file used in ViewProfileService.java class
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ExpandableListView
                    android:id="@+id/lvExp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>  

    </LinearLayout>


    your ExpandableListAdapter.java class ..
    -------------------------------------

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.app.ruzanamah.R;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .get(childPosititon);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

            txtListChild.setText(childText);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return this._listDataHeader.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            }

            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }


    your list_item.xml file used in ExpandableListAdapter.java class
    ---------------------------------------------------------------

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

    </LinearLayout>

    your list_group.xml file used in ExpandableListAdapter.java class
    -------------------------------------------------------------------

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        >
     <!-- android:background="#000000" -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:textSize="17dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    Above mentioned contains all you need to perform your stuff very efficiently..

    Enjoy .. !
```